# ¿cómo puedo imprimir la vista que recibo?

Tags: html, jquery

lo que sucede es que tengo un método ajax en el que recibo una tabla en html y quisiera poder imprimirla en otro html el ajax con el que la recibo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#formualrioListarProductosXTipoProducto").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id_tipo_producto = $('.id_tipo_producto').val();
        console.log(id_tipo_producto);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "tablaProductoXTipo.php",
            data: { id_tipo_producto: id_tipo_producto},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#printArea").printArea(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error" + data);
            }
        })
    })
```

intente imprimirla con ese printArea pero no lo logre,tam bien intente sacar la variable data pero cuando la guardaba en otra variable me la dejaba como un unico string, la vista que recibo es la siguiente:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive dataTable" name="formulario" id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre Tipo Producto</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                        <tr>
            <th>probando</th>              
            </tr>
                        <tr>
            <th>sonido</th>              
            </tr>
                        <tr>
            <th>probando</th>              
            </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

¿cómo podria hacer para imprimirla dentro de este div que esta en la otra pagina donde necesito visualizar la tabla?

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="printArea">
</div>
```

agradezco de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: Pero ven, printArea es literalmente para imprimir , lo que necesitas es mostrar texto html que te llega en otra pagina ? o necesitas mostrar lo que llega y imprimirlo

Comment: necesito mostrar la tabla que llega en pantalla dentro del div con id printArea

Comment: Cuando te digo que es literalmenta para imprimir es por que improme la pagina mira este ejemplo (https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/imprimir/index.html)    que lo saque de aqui  https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/imprimir-zona-de-la-pagina-con-jquery/

Comment: jajaja no imprimirlo asi literalmente, lo que quiero es mostrar el texto html que me llega en la otra pagina

Comment: ok jajaja ya te dejo un ejemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La informacion que te llega en este caso la tabla la puedes recibir en una variable y luego setearla en el div que necesitas.

Te dejo un snippet funcional, ya para imprimr la tabla tienes que usar la liberia de jquery PrintArea o el que quieras.

Con esta linea pintas el html que te llega en el div:

```
 $("#idInfoAjax").html(htmlAjax);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const htmlAjax = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive dataTable" name="formulario" id="table_id"><thead> <tr><th>Nombre Tipo Producto</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody>          <tr>  <th>probando</th> </tr>  <tr>  <th>sonido</th> </tr> <tr>  <th>probando</th>   </tr> </tbody></table>';
 
  $("#idInfoAjax").html(htmlAjax);
})

$('#imprimir').click(function(){
    $('#idInfoAjax').printArea();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="imprimir">
  Imprimir Area
</button>
<br><br>

<div class="col-sm-3" id="idInfoAjax">
</div>
```

Comment: ufffff muchas gracias